# Gradle DSL method not found 'getPackageLibrary()'

Tags: android, gradle

I imported an Android library project into Android Studio and I got this error message: `Gradle DSL method not found 'getPackageLibrary()'`. I suppose the version of the Gradle plugin does not support this method. I would like to find out a replacement for this method, which is used in `build.gradle` as follows:

```
variant.getPackageLibrary().dependsOn(copyToInsideProtectedApp)
```

I suppose it is something similar to replacing `run proGuard()` by `minifyEnabled` which I already did. I use Android Studio 1.0.2.

Does anybody know a replacement for getPackageLibrary? Search on Internet didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some codes on AOSP [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/9fba95348ef762fd9a7c82ac332d119684a74bcb/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/api/LibraryVariantImpl.java), it says that

> variant.getPackageLibrary() is deprecated. Call it on one of
>   variant.getOutputs() instead.

The code is as below.

```
// ---- Deprecated, will be removed in 1.0
//STOPSHIP
@Override
public Zip getPackageLibrary() {
    // if more than one output, refuse to use this method
    if (outputs.size() > 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format(
                "More than one output on variant '%s', cannot call getPackageLibrary() on it. Call it on one of its outputs instead.",
                getName()));
    }
    // deprecation warning.
    plugin.displayDeprecationWarning("variant.getPackageLibrary() is deprecated. Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.");
    // use the single output for compatibility.
    return ((LibraryVariantOutput) outputs.get(0)).getPackageLibrary();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used variant.getOutputs() instead but I get another error:

Comment: The new error is: Error:(67, 0) No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.dependsOn() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy_Decorated) values: [task ':crypto:g4jcrypto-ArxanDebugCopyJarTo}']